# CSRF Token is not set..How to set CSRF cookie in Typescript?

Tags: python, json, typescript, django-csrf

as title I have no idea how to set CSRF token inside my typescript file, I am a beginner about typescript and CSRF Token.

This is the typescript file I use to post my info.

```
getUsers2() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let body2 = {
      site: this.selectedSite,
      zone: this.selectedZone,
      user: this.username,
      categoryType: this.problemType,
      ser: 'High',
      conNo:'012-8888888'
    };

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/apidb/report/', JSON.stringify(body2), {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("herererererere" ,data);
        });


    this.restProvider.getUsers2().then(data2 => {
      this.locations = data2;
      console.log(this.locations);
    });
  }
```

Inside my setting.py I have already install the middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

In my views.py I not sure about is this correct or not

```
def report(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        z1= site(country_site="New Penang Site")
        site.save()
    else:
        return HttpResponse(request.method, content_type="application/json")
```

When I post a data to my API it shows me that CSRF is not set..

[image]

Can anyone provide me any tutorial or guideline about this problem ?? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

you have to append the CSRF token to the POSTdata sent in HTTPrequest (in this case your body2 var). You'll have to check Django docs for what name they are looking for in POST (in Laravel, its '_token').

the value of this POST var will be set by echoing the token server side at the top of the page (i.e. var x = (server-side echo of CSRF token);)

Comment: the POST var should be place inside my typescript or views.py ??

Comment: I still not very clear about the solution you provide.. do you mind to explain more ?